# Property observer not getting hit, but value is changing

Tags: swift, xcode, didset, property-observer

I have got a variable which seems to be changing throughout the app. I have confirmed this by when I originally change a value to be true and then print, it shows that it is then false, false, false, true, false, false, false and my property observed is hit so "It changed!" shows in the console.

However, I later print this out again and it has reverted back to false, despite nothing changing the value of it (that I can see) and the property observer is not hit. It does not print "It changed" but in the console, it then prints false, false, false, false, false, false, false.

```
var isPicked: [Bool] = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false] {

            didSet {

                print("It changed!")
            }
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you show how you change your `isPicked` variable and the context of your prints ?

Comment: I figured it out. It was a local variable so was being recreated every time I changed screen. Thanks for your help @Zico